# weird Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of null at onSuccessMapUnitFields

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dynamics-crm

This code was running fine until I decided to add 4 more lines of code, so I removed them. But I got this error, funny thing is I added my lines on the `Form_onload` function. I need help with this.

```
function Form_OnLoad() {
    debugger;
        if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1) {
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("quantity").setValue(1);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("quantity").setSubmitMode("always");
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("isproductoverridden").setValue(true);

  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("isproductoverridden").setSubmitMode("always");
        }
        else {
            ActOnFields("disable", "ir_unit");
            ActOnFields("show", "salesorderid");
        }
    }

    function Unit_OnChange() {
        var Unit = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ir_unit").getValue();
        if (Unit != null && Unit.length > 0) {
            var lookupid = Unit[0].id;
            var oDataSetName = "ir_unitSet";
            var columns = "ir_AmountRate,ir_Expenses,ir_PublishedRate";
            var filter = "ir_unitId eq (guid'" + lookupid + "')";
            retrieveMultiple(oDataSetName, columns, filter, "", onSuccessMapUnitFields);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("productdescription").setValue(Unit[0].name);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("productdescription").setSubmitMode("always");
        }
        else {
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("priceperunit").setValue(null);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("priceperunit").setSubmitMode("always");
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount").setValue(null);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount").setSubmitMode("always");
        }
    }
    function onSuccessMapUnitFields(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            var price = 0;
            //if (data[0].ir_AmountRate != null && data[0].ir_AmountRate.Value != null) {
            //price += parseFloat(eval(data[0].ir_AmountRate.Value));
            //}
            if (data[0].ir_PublishedRate != null) {
                price += parseFloat(eval(data[0].ir_PublishedRate));
            }
            if (data[0].ir_Expenses != null && data[0].ir_Expenses.Value != null) {
                price += parseFloat(eval(data[0].ir_Expenses.Value));
            }
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("priceperunit").setValue(price);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("priceperunit").setSubmitMode("always");
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount").setValue(price);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount").setSubmitMode("always");
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ir_publishedrate").setValue(price);
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ir_publishedrate").setSubmitMode("always");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `debugger;` inside `Unit_OnChange` function & the success callback function `onSuccessMapUnitFields`, then while debugging you can figure out that which one of the 3 fields among `priceperunit`, `baseamount`, `ir_publishedrate` is throwing this error.

Also verify if you are calling `ActOnFields` method to hide those 3 fields anywhere else before calling this `setValue(price)`. Because if the control/attribute is not visible in the form - `Xrm.Page.getAttribute` returns **null**, then when you are trying to `setValue` it fails with this error.

Failsafe approach:

```
if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount") != null){
       Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount").setValue(price);
       Xrm.Page.getAttribute("baseamount").setSubmitMode("always");
}
```