# Create static URL hyperlink in Dynamics CRM form via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I would like to create a field on a form that users can click on to reference a sharepoint file that is in a static location.  I created a script and added it to the page but I'm getting an error message.  Can anyone please help?

Script:

```
function createUrl () {
    var VersionSpreadsheet = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com";
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_VersionSpreadsheet").setValue(VersionSpreadsheet);
}
```

Error:

> One of the scripts for this record has caused an error. For more
> details, download the log file. TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'setValue' of null at createUrl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [weird Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of null at onSuccessMapUnitFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519357/weird-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setvalue-of-null-at-onsuccessmapun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute names are case sensitive and it should be all lowercase. Also the shortcut and crisp version is below.

```
function createUrl () {
    var VersionSpreadsheet = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com";
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_versionspreadsheet").setValue(VersionSpreadsheet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I reviewed the attribute closer and found another mistake.