# Getting weird behavior in useRef() object React-Native component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref

I am working with the OTP auto-fill feature. I am using [react-native-otp-textinput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-textinput), which is working fine. I am using **useRef()** for the OTP Textfield, so when I receive a SMS, I will use this `useRef()`, and fill it in the value.

**Problem Statement:**

1. When I run the app for the first time, my `useRef()` behaves fine, and I can auto fill the item with `userRef().current.setValue()`.
2. When I run the app for the second or third time, I always get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of null, js engine: hermes

What I did was to capture, what was the reason behind it. So I did console it out in my function. I found out for the first time, `console.log(useRef().current)` prints the data, but when it comes to second or third time, it returns **null**. I am confused, why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
 const otpInputRef = useRef(null);

 const startReadSMSListerner = async () => {
   // Checking permission, else getting one
   const hasPermission = await ReadSms.requestReadSMSPermission();
   // If given permission, start listening, else, leave it
   if(hasPermission){
     ReadSms.startReadSMS((status, sms, error) => {
       if(status === 'success'){
         console.log(otpInputRef.current); // <-- Comes fine for the first time, but null when we test it in the second time
         otpInputRef?.current.setValue(sms); // <--- Here is the code which is working weird
       }
     });
   }
 }
 
 useEffect(() => {
  if(Platform.OS === 'android') startReadSMSListerner();

  return () => ReadSms.stopReadSMS();
 }, [otpInputRef]);
```

I am totally confused on this, tried following this up: [TypeError: Cannot read property of setValue of null JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519357/weird-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setvalue-of-null-at-onsuccessmapun).

### Edit

Here is how my OTP TextInput looks in JSX

```js
            <OTPTextInput
              ref={otpInputRef}
              defaultValue=""
              inputCount={4}
              keyboardType="numeric"
              returnKeyType="done"
              textContentType="oneTimeCode" // for iOS Autofill enable
              containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', padding: width / 15}}
              textInputStyle={styles.textInputContainer}
              handleTextChange={(text) => onChangetText(text)}
            />
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used the `setValue` method of `useRef` and cannot find any mention of it in the docs. Where did you see it?

Comment: @Konstantin `setValue` is a method of OTP text input (see the link in the question)

Comment: Can you please share the render part of your component, how exactly do you define OTPTextInput in JSX?

Comment: Hey @yuvin I have added the code in **EDIT** section. Let me know if you need anything else from my side.

Comment: This probably won't address this particular issue, but in general when you access the ref, do `ref.current?.` instead of `ref?.current` (ref itself is always defined, but the `current` prop might not).

Comment: What if you try replacing `ref={otpInputRef}` with a callback ref as suggested in the component example: `ref={e => (otpInputRef = e)}` ? Just an idea...

Comment: Tried already @yuvin it throws an error, saying `TypeError: "otpInputRef" is read-only`

Comment: Hm... Maybe it should be `let` then instead if `const`. Does that component work at all? :)

Comment: You mention that it works for the first time, but then you run the app for the second time and it doesn't work anymore. What exactly happens in between? Do you close the app? Or do you just wait for the next SMS to arrive?

Comment: Yes it works @yuvin for the first time. So by second time, I just `logout`, and `login` again. OTP is just `2FA` in my system.

Comment: So I guess your OTP component (which contains OTPTextInput) is reloaded (unmounted/mounted) when you logout and login again? I'm trying to create some sample code to reproduce this

Comment: @yuvin you saved my life on this `let` part. Changing the `const` to `let` for my `otpInputRef` worked for me. Since it was a part of the `useRef`, so it was not updating immediately due to that. Now we have `let`, it makes the changes as soon we assign it to the `<TextInput>` :D. You are savior. Please write an answer, and I will upvote it or let me know, I will write the answer in brief for our future developers :D

Comment: Glad that it worked! I never had an opportunity to have a closer look at React Native so this was a good chance for me :) I used [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) and I like how it easily integrates and runs on my device. I'll add an answer, feel free to upvote it or edit if needed

Comment: Do it and let me know @yuvin I will edit and upvote your answer. Will be waiting for that. You deserve an upvote my friend :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` **should not** be used as a datatype for the `ref`, it **should be** `let`. Reason being as per the lifecycle of React-Native:

> View loads first, and useEffect updates afterwards, so const was just initialising ref value as null only. let enabled the ref useRef() value to update, and make the job easier

```
 // This does the magic
 let otpInputRef = useRef(null);

 const startReadSMSListerner = async () => {
   // Checking permission, else getting one
   const hasPermission = await ReadSms.requestReadSMSPermission();
   // If given permission, start listening, else, leave it
   if(hasPermission){
     ReadSms.startReadSMS((status, sms, error) => {
       if(status === 'success'){
         otpInputRef.current?.setValue(sms); // <--- Works now, since it gets updated in the useEffect() call
       }
     });
   }
 } 

 useEffect(() => {
  if(Platform.OS === 'android') startReadSMSListerner();

  return () => ReadSms.stopReadSMS();
 }, [otpInputRef]);
```

Comment: Thank you Yuvin for the answer, I have improved the answer. Thank you for your suggestion :)